# Why is Wkhtmltopdf not showing the header and footer in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, wkhtmltopdf

I try to print PDF report from Odoo system. I have installed this:

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Odoo v10.0
- `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 (with patched qt)`

Before I got this problem I had to `apt update && apt upgrade` and `wkhtmltopdf` has been updated version also.

[image: pdf]

Comment: Try with [this version](https://builds.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12.1.3/wkhtmltox_0.12.1.3-1~bionic_amd64.deb)

Comment: I had the same question in PHP. If you didn't find anything yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071571/wkhtmltopdf-knplabs-snappy-not-showing-header-nor-footer-page